# PM2 very slow startup with errors, blocking server startup, even SSH

Tags: node.js, systemd, pm2

I have configured starting my server with:

```
npm i -g pm2
pm2 start "node /service/www.js" --name myservice
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

Then I reboot the server and see on display Ubuntu start process:

```
[...] A start job is running for pm2 process manager
```

for ~3 min.
At this moment I'm even unable to connect via SSH: after successful login I do not get Sh/Bash prompt.
But Apache already serves static HTML files at this stage.

Then I see:

```
[...] Failed to start pm2 process manager
      See: systemctl status pm2-root.service
```

for ~3 min. SSH is still unavailable.
After some time I see Ubuntu's messages like:

```
[...] Reached ...blah-blah-some-service
```

And after ~3 min more I get Bash's prompt of SSH!

And, surprise!.. PM2 is working well on this stage, `systemctl status pm2-root.service` shows no problems.

How to fix it and let PM2 start without a delay causing blocking Linux server boot process?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: But this is one question. PM has a huge delay on startup blocking server to load.